# Compare Array element with string inside linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this model:

```
 public class Model_Test
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }            
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string[] Prop3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Check that `Prop3` is an array.

Values inside `Prop3` are like `{"answer1","answer2","answer3"}`

I need to do a query that takes only the `Model_Test` objects where `answer3` is "Yes", I'm triyng this:

```
result = from q in Model_Test
         where q.Prop3[2] == "Yes"                    
         select new { Name = Prop1, Value = Prop2 };
```

When I execute this query I get this error:

**Unrecognized expression node : ArrayIndex**

I think the problem is in this part of my query: `q.Prop3[2]`

I appreciate your help.

Comment: ``Model_Test`` is a collection in the query code block?

Comment: Yes Model_Test is a collection

Comment: and this: ``Name = Prop1, Value = Prop2`` should be : ``Name = `q.Prop1, Value = q.Prop2``

Comment: it is linq to sql or iinq to entities

Comment: It is not linq to sql

Comment: How can `Model_Test` be a collection and be the name of a class....??

Comment: @LuisLora What query provider *are* you using?

Comment: Model_Test represents a data collection, I think we can change for q in Model_Test by for q in collectionOfModel_Test

Comment: Also, looks like what you want is a `bool[] Prop3` that contains `true/false`

Comment: I'm using linq.... System.Linq

Comment: Yes @singsuyash it could work

Comment: this works fine for me. a collection of `Model_Test`  with 3 `Model_Test` and also filled properties to test it correctly

Comment: i have to mention that i changed `new { Name = Prop1, Value = Prop2 };` in to `new { Name = q.Prop1, Value = q.Prop2 };`

Comment: And do you want those `Model_test` elements from your `Model_test`'s collection which contain at least 1 `true` value in the `bool[] Prop3` ? sorry it should be at index 2, misread the question, updating this comment.

Comment: I could use bool Prop3 in my model, but in a method I return an string[] array with 3 values the last element is "Yes" or "No". It fits in Prop3 definition

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that expression parser does not know how to translate the array index operation into equivalent SQL. 
You can use any greedy operator (ToArray() for example) to fetch all data and then filter it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a basic linq `where` query:

```
// Your Model
public class Model_Test
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }            
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public bool[] Prop3 { get; set; }
    }

//Usage
List<Model_Test> lst = new List<Model_Test>(){
        new Model_Test{Prop1="Foo", Prop2="Bar",Prop3 = new bool[]{true,false,true}},
        new Model_Test{Prop1="Foo2", Prop2="Bar2",Prop3 = new bool[]{true,false,false}},
        new Model_Test{Prop1="Foo3", Prop2="Bar3",Prop3 = new bool[]{true,false,true}},
    };

    // Query Expression
    var result = from element in lst
                where element.Prop3[2] == true
                select new {Name = element.Prop1, Value = element.Prop2};

    // Lambda Expression    
    var result2 = lst.Where(x=>x.Prop3[2]==true).Select(x=> new {Name=x.Prop1, Value = x.Prop2});
```

But you need to be sure that there *will* be a value at `Prop3[2]` or this will throw exceptions.